# Starting in normal mode on bash

Tags: bash

I was very happy to discover that I could use vi keybindings in the bash shell (bash vi mode). I am a little frustrated now however that the shell always defaults to insert mode rather than normal mode. I keep having to exit it. Is there a way I could have it start in normal mode instead?

Thank you!

Comment: Having trouble getting a more authoritative source, but https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rluserman.html says that vi mode starts off in insert mode.

Comment: Add `set +o vi` to your `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following lines in `~/.inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-m": "\C-j\e"
set keymap vi-command
"\C-m": "\C-j\e"
```

Or use `bind` in `~/.bashrc`:

```
set -o vi
bind -m vi-insert '"\C-m": "\C-j\e"'
bind -m vi-command '"\C-m": "\C-j\e"'
```

Now you automatically issue `accept-line` followed by `vi-movement-mode`  by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> for `accept-line` only.

I admit they have some flaws:

- You're in insert mode in the beginning
- You'll have trobule when you paste multiple command lines from your terminal

Comment: I like this in principle, but it is very fragile. Do you know of a way where you could use something related to printing the prompt to enter normal-mode?